# OpenID on mobile apps

Tags: mobile, openid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OpenID on a mobile/cell phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302913/openid-on-a-mobile-cell-phone)

I am trying to implement OpenID support for my website. Down the line, I would need to create mobile app versions as well. I am not a big fan of the UI with OpenID - the way the user is taken out of the workflow to get authenticated. And I am thinking that it will be evern worse in case of mobile apps.

Can anyone point me to an existing solution that I can see? Is it even possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You embed a browser in your app and use it your app. In android use `WebView`, in iOS use `UIWebView`. Take a look on [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tP6FtXfXTfc&feature=BFa&list=SP64D87C03BA3B2A88&lf=list_related) around time 47:30.